Failed to Execute lifecycle deploy due to failed action: {"name":"install dependencies","uses":"cli/runDotnetCommand"}
I am trying to start microsoft teams app (.NET + React) locally but i get error while starting it using Teams Toolkit in VSC. The error i get is
[Error] - Failed to Execute lifecycle deploy due to failed action: {"name":"install dependencies","uses":"cli/runDotnetCommand"}. ScriptExecutionError:Unable to execute script action.. Env output: {"SSL_CRT_FILE":"C:/Users/user/.fx/certificate/localhost.crt","SSL_KEY_FILE":"C:/Users/user/.fx/certificate/localhost.key","DOTNET_PATH":"C:\\Users\\user\\.fx\\bin\\dotnet"}
summary
Do you have any idea what might be a problem?

you can use the Teams Toolkit in Visual Studio to develop a .NET Teams app. Additionally, the Teams Toolkit in VS Code supports projects in Node.js and Python.
